# Convert from string to long in a service in android..?

Tags: android

In my application I am passing a string value from the edittext to the service where I have defined this

```
( t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Task(), 0, long); )
```

How to convert from string to long in a service...? or is there any other method to pass a long value to the service...?

Comment: long l = Long.parseLong(string);

Comment: Have you tried casting it to long. If your string represents a valid long you could try casting it to long like this : ((long)string)

Answer (score 4):

this method use to convert string to Long.

```
long l = Long.parseLong(string);
```

Comment: yes, I tried that but Service class does not support Long. its throwing NumberFormatException..

Comment: try { long l = Long.parseLong(string) } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }, then tell me more description about Exception from log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method for convert your string to long and after that you have passed that long variable to your service

```
long l = Long.parseLong(yourstring);
```